# Gitbash Error - rbenv: cannot find readlink - are you missing GNU coreutils?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git-bash

Hello when i open git hub i get an error right at the top.

It literally looks like this:

```
rbenv: cannot find readlink - are you missing GNU coreutils?
rbenv: cannot find readlink - are you missing GNU coreutils?

Joey@JOEY-PC /c/Sites (master)
```

$

Everything was working great before i installed rubyinstall 1.9.3.

Then my local server wasn't working when i tried to run a new website im making.

So i reverted back to ruby 2.1.5p273 by running rubyinstaller 2.1.5

Anyone know what the problem is?

Here is what my server looks like when once the above error started to appear on gitbash

http://i57.tinypic.com/b5p7nm.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It is coming from here: `https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/blob/master/libexec/rbenv`.  Look in your `~/.rbenv` installation, specifically `~/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv`.

It happened to me because my Git for Windows installation lacks the `readlink` command.

Try commenting out the READLINK section and replace `resolve_link` with this:

```
resolve_link() { sed -n -e 's/\x00//g'  -e 's/\!<symlink>..//p' $1; }
```

I still not sure this really works, though.